# как работать с usb в ядре?

Tags: c

хочу написать ядро с некоторыми функциями. Как с помощью C написать программу которая: "при подключение в usb гнездо устройства флешкой, активировало передачу данных на некоторое время, допустим на 20 секунд, и за эти 20 секунд переменная находящаяся в флешке передавалась в устройство." В общем это работало как замок(скрипт хранящийся в устройстве) и ключ (переменная, которая активирует скрипт на устройстве)

Comment: А причём тут ядро? И какое ядро - линух или винда? Вы сами-то осознаёте, что хотите написать?

Comment: Конечно осознаю, возможно не так выражаю. Я думаю было понятно что линукс. Ядро потому что это должно работать как драйвер устройства. Возможно ли это? Или просто можете объяснить как работает usb в ядре linux и скинуть ссылку на книгу или материал, написал я выше в качестве примера, что я хочу сделать.

Comment: С подобным заданием наверное будет проще воспользоваться libusb.

Comment: А зачем для этого драйвер? И что мешает, к примеру, просто закинуть на флешку самый обыкновенный файл с этим самым ключом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"это должно работать как драйвер устройства."

Что значит **как** ?! Либо ядро, либо **не** ядро. Либо нулевое кольцо, либо не нулевое. **как** не бывает.

Но, если не придираться к словам, а попытаться догадаться (!) о Ваших намерениях, то тогда (скорее всего) Вам надо ознакомиться с технологией *systemd*, которая в современных ядрах (в частности) реализует обработку подключения устройств. Разных, не обязательно USB.

Конкретно Ваша проблема решается с помощью юниты типа *.device*, которую Вы должны подключить к *sysnemd*. Тема эта не простая. Для начала, можно посмотреть вот это:

https://linux-notes.org/pishem-systemd-unit-fajl/